# Using python to generate unique IDs

Tags: python, unique-id

How should I assign a unique ID (UID) to a group of rows and a different UID where there is a sudden jump in ID values. For example; assign "1" to ID values ranging from 122 to 125 and a UID of "2" where ID values range from 507 to 511 in the table below.

| Name | ID | UID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | 122 |  |
| T1 | 123 |  |
| T1 | 124 |  |
| T1 | 125 |  |
| T1 | 507 |  |
| T1 | 508 |  |
| T1 | 509 |  |
| T1 | 510 |  |
| T1 | 511 |  |

To be honest i don't know where to start from.

Comment: Are you using pandas or is this data in a nested list or a dictionary or something?

Comment: [Find a simpler problem!](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/)

Comment: From @surviving-grad (not enough rep. to comment): *Is this a pandas dataframe? When you say "assign "1" to ID values ranging from 122 to 125 and a UID of "2" where ID values range from 507 to 511", do you want to group the dataframe based on some condition?

If yes, you can try using pandas [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function*

Comment: you want something called Unique ID (UID) to have a value of 1 for several rows and a value of 2 for another several rows. then why you call it "Unique ID" it's it's not unique? That will be a very misleading name. Could you modify your question and sill the UID column with the values you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want an *unique* id, but just a *group* id, where a group is a set of rows with consecutive ID values. Assuming pandas, you could use `shift()` to identify consecutive values, and then `cumsum()` to automatically build a *group id*:

```
df['UID'] = (df['ID'] != df['ID'].shift() + 1).cumsum()
```

It gives as expected:

```
df
  Name   ID  UID
0   T1  122    1
1   T1  123    1
2   T1  124    1
3   T1  125    1
4   T1  507    2
5   T1  508    2
6   T1  509    2
7   T1  510    2
8   T1  511    2
```

Comment: Thanks so much Serge Ballesta. It definitely solves my problems!

Comment: You are right Serge Ballesta, what i wanted was a group_ID because ID column is actually the Unique_ID. However, I'm happy with the solution you suggested.